# ffmpeg generate higher quality images for MJPEG encoding

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264

I have a bunch of mov / H.264 files, that I'd like to encode into mov/MJPEG. However I'm getting very low quality output. Here's what I tried:

```
ffmpeg -i a.mov -an -crf 11 -preset slower -pix_fmt yuv420p -vcodec mjpeg -f mov -y b.mov
```

For H.264 encoding the `-crf` and `-preset` flags generate higher quality. But that doesn't seem to work for MJPEG.

Comment: mjpeg is an intra-frame compression scheme only. It looks at a frame, compresses it with jpeg specs, then moves on the the next frame. It doesn't make sense for it to have -crf. -crf is a protocol for an inter-frame compression scheme, where the algorithm tries to save disc space by looking across frames for ways to compress the data rate. I recommend ffmpeg questions to be asked a video.stackexchange.com, neither SO nor SU.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

## Use `-q:v` to control (M)JPEG quality

The effective range is a linear scale of 2-31, and a lower value will result in a higher quality output.

#### Examples

Make MJPEG video in MOV container:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -c:v mjpeg -q:v 3 -an output.mov
```

Output a series of JPG images:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -q:v 2 images_%04d.jpg
```

Files will be named `images_0001.jpg`, `images_0002.jpg`, `images_0003.jpg`, etc.

---

## Private options

> For H.264 encoding the `-crf` and `-preset` flags generate higher quality. But that doesn't seem to work for MJPEG.

The MJPEG encoder does not use `-crf` and `-preset`; these are ["private" options](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#AVOptions) for some encoders such as libx264, libx265, and libvpx. You can see private options like this: `ffmpeg -h encoder=mjpeg`.